# Como alterar height de tabela?

Tags: html, css

Estou desenvolvendo o site da empresa onde trabalho e preciso que a tabela de downloads que aparece no [site](http://lucaswmolin.com/zenite/amostra_1/add/suporte.php) preencha a tela toda. Imagino que o *height* teria que estar em 100%, mas quando faço essa alteração, não acontece nada.

```
<table style="width: 100%;height: 100%" align='center' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
```

Comment: poste seu código inteiro, heigth: 100%, depende dos containeres para funcionar.

Comment: Voce pode usar `height: 100vh;`

Comment: O código é muito extenso pra colocar aqui... é só ir na página e dar Ctrl + U.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto, funcionou parcialmente... Agora faltaria eliminar os espaços em branco em cima e embaixo da tabela.

Comment: @RafaelAugusto, como posso alinhar o texto da célula para baixo? <td style:'vertical-align: bottom'>

Comment: Consegui... <td style='vertical-align: bottom'>

Comment: para consultar o suporte de vh nos browsers acesse http://caniuse.com/viewport-units/embed/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `height` é relativo ao *container* no qual o elemento está contido.

Considerando que o *container* da sua tabela é o próprio `body` do documento, é necessário que o documento também possua altura 100%. Para isso, uma forma de definir a altura `height=100%` do documento (*body, html*) é aplicar no CSS:

```
<style>
html, body{ height: 100%; }
</style>
```

Desta forma, sua tabela com `height:100%` irá ter a mesma altura do documento (área visível do navegador).

*Pode-se usar também o `100vh` no elemento (`height:100vh`), mas alguns navegadores mais antigos não suportam esse valor `vh` (ex. Safari para Windows, Safari e Chrome em iPhones mais antigos).*

**Outra solução com jQuery, sem o CSS citado acima:**

```
<table id="id_tabela" style="width: 100%;" align='center' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>

<script>
$(window).on('load resize',function(){
    $("#id_tabela").css("height",window.innerWidth+"px");
});
</script>
```